# Get client id using multithreaded java server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, server

I'm currently trying to create a multithreaded java socket server.
I can send "private" messages using "ID;MESSAGE; in my clients.

The messages arrive at the right client but the problem is that the server always displays that all messages come from the same client (client id 0), but they don't.

Here's my Server http://pastebin.com/Dzh5Ynvj

Server output

```
21:02:55 [DSS-Server] [Client#0] connected.
21:02:58 [DSS-Server] [Client#1] connected.
21:13:11 [DSS-Server] [Client#0] > 0;This is send from client 0
21:13:18 [DSS-Server] [Client#0] > 1;This also
21:13:30 [DSS-Server] [Client#0] > 0;But this comes from client 1
```

Comment: Can you also post your Client code? And how is the server receiving messages from the clients?

Comment: Oh god I forgot half of the information :/ Here's the client handler http://pastebin.com/z7bdX4sL and here basically the client http://pastebin.com/KwxkpGCW

Comment: @AlonDattner Your constructor should not catch that exception: it should throw it. If the `BufferedReader` can't be constructed for any reason, the enture object is useless, so letting it be returned to the caller of `new ClientHandler()` is pointless.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to fix this too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ClientHandler` code, you have not assigned the `id` parameter to the `id` member of your class.

```
public ClientHandler(Socket client, int id) {
   this.id = id; // ADD THIS LINE
    try {

        //Get BufferedReader from client
        this.client = client;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Add `this.id = id;` in your `ClientHandler` constructor. That should do it.